# AngularDart: "logical pages" and views are 1-to-1 or 1-to-many or what?

Tags: view, dart, angular-dart, angular-routing

What is the relationship between an app's "**logical pages**" and **views** in AngularDart (or JS)?

For example, in the context of the [AngularDart tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/wiki) Recipe Book example, I originally considered "view recipe" and "edit recipe" as *logical pages* (or as an app steady state as @pavelgj suggests).

When I started working through the [AngularDart tutorial](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/wiki) I thought that 
a logical pages and Angular "views" were in one-to-one correspondence. But in Chapter 6, views are treated as *part of* a the `index.html` page (which is used to generate "view recipe" and "edit recipe"):

```html
  <!-- ... more page elements here ... -->
  <section id="details">
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </section>
```

If a view can be *part of* a page, can a page contain multiple views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what do you mean by a "web page"? Angular.dart is used to build [Single-page applications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application), so technically the whole angular app is a single web page.

We can expand the definition of a "page" to: stable state of the browser after the user performed an action. That would make term "page" meaningful for single-page applications.

Using the new definition of page: Because angular views can be nested and composed of other views they are not the same thing as a page. Page can be a collection of views. So page to view is 1-to-many. However, for most relatively simple applications that use flat routing that relationship is usually 1-to-1.